# How to iterate over successively-increasing-length slices of the characters in a string?

Tags: python, string, range, iteration, slice

I'm trying to iterate over a string in a specific way but encountered some problems and got confused.

```
input = "abcdefghijkl"

def iterate_chars(word):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        sliced = word[:i]
        print(i)
        print(result)
```

But in this piece of code `i` prints 0 and therefore nothing is printed for result. 
If I try to iterate over `for i in word`, I get the following for sliced:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

What I need is for the programm to iterate over a given string character by character starting at position `[2]`. So the output will look like this:

```
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
etc.
```

I've also tried this:

```
for i in range(2, len(word), 1) # prints nothing, doesn't start loop
for i in range(0, len(word), 1) # prints 0 for i
```

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range returns values *less* than it's end value.

If I understand what you are trying to do properly, this does the trick:

```
for i in range(2, len(word)+1):
    print(word[:i])
```

If word is `"foobar"`, this will print:

```
fo
foo
foob
fooba
foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, just take another look at what your `range` needs to iterate over. Start at position 2, and go through the rest of the word.

```
def iterate_chars(word):
    for i in range(2, len(word)+1):
        sliced = word[:i]
        print(sliced)
```

Comment: `range` also works with a single argument, *end*. *start* defaults to 0 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not care about the order than you can give a try

```
text = "hello"
chars = sorted(text) # ['e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
def checkPermutation(str1, str2):
  count=0
  if (len(str1) != len(str2)):
    return False
  else:
    for i in range(len(str1)):
      if str2[i] in (str1):
          count += 1
    if count == len(str2):
      return True
    else:
      return False


# print(checkPermutation("ABC", "CBA")) will return true
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting answers, please mention how your code works and/or how it resolves the OP's problem :)